# Socialite Package This page isn't working

Tags: php, facebook, laravel-5, laravel-socialite

I have applied socialite package in my project following the Laravel Socialite Documentation https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/socialite

The problem arises when I try to login/register a user it throws this particular error [image]

I have already checked my URL's on facebook panel as well as on my side.
The code is as follows:-

```
Route::get('customer/{provider}', ['as' => 'customer.social-login', 'uses' => 'CustomerController@redirectToProvider']);
Route::get('customer/{provider}/callback', ['uses' => 'CustomerController@handleProviderCallback']);
```

Controller

```
public function redirectToProvider($provider)
{
    return Socialite::driver($provider)
        ->redirect();
}


public function handleProviderCallback($provider)
{
    dd($provider);//Not reaching here
}
```

Services.php file

```
'facebook' => [
    'client_id' => 'xxxxxx',
    'client_secret' => 'xxxxxx',
    'redirect' => 'http://localhost:8000/customer/facebook/callback',
],
```

Comment: Could it be that your configured `redirect` is pointing to localhost ?

Comment: I don't think it's the issue as in earlier projects it was working fine. I have tried changing the redirect point and it redirected, but when the redirect point is saved as above it throws the error shown in the screenshot. @Mike

Comment: can you check the response header, which url its redirect to?